# How does Java handle using a getter on a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

For instance, if I have the below for loop declaration.

`for(Foo f : fooService.getFooList()){}`

Is it more efficient to call the getter first and assign it to a temporary `List<Foo> fooList = fooService.getFooList();` or is it ok to use the getter inline?

Comment: The only difference between these two is style.  They are functionally identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, with a foreach loop, I expect your code will compile to something like this:

```
Iterator<Foo> it = fooService.getFooList().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Foo foo = it.next();
    // ...
}
```

So in this case it doesn't make a difference.

However if you were to use a different kind of loop, then it might make a difference. For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < fooService.getFooList().size(); i++){
    Foo foo = fooService.getFooList().get(i);
    // ...
}
```

If your list is exposed to external modification, then it's unlikely that the compiler could prove that the list size wont change, so it will call `getFooList().size()` each iteration to compare against `i`, so there would be some slight added overhead.

But note that if the list size changes then `i < fooService.getFooList().size()` reflects that. This can be useful if you are aware of it but dangerous if you aren't.

If you know that the list size wont change then you could do something like this to eliminate that overhead (or just use an `Iterator` or enhanced for-each loop if you don't need the indices):

```
List<Foo> fooList = fooService.getFooList();
final int fooListSize = fooList.size();
for(int i = 0; i < fooListSize ; i++){
    Foo foo = fooList.get(i);
    // ...
}
```

Despite all this, you should probably prefer readability over micro optimization.

But if your application is runtime sensitive and your list is large and these small checks are adding up, then you may want to do something like the above.

Answer (score 1):

It's not more efficient to assign to a List reference first, but having the reference may be useful, depending upon what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is about the `fooService.getFooList()` being called `n` times for getting every value `f` disregard that thought. This calls `getFooList()` once and iterates over its result.

For example in the following [snippet](https://ideone.com/4E0KAM):

```
class Ideone
{
    private static List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        for(String f : getFooList()){
           System.out.println(f);
        }
    }

    private static List<String> getFooList() {
        System.out.println("getFooList called");
        return list;
    }
}
```

`getFooList called` is printed only once which indicates that the method `getFooList()` is invoked only once by the for-loop. After that it is printed `A`, `B`, `C`, the iteration over the elements gotten from the method invokation.

So, **in terms of efficiency**, **it is the same** calling the getter directly or assigning it to a variable and using this for performing the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the same. The getter is called once, not before completing each loop. Assign it to a variable if you need it, otherwise it is not necessary.

FYI : behind the scene the `List` won't be used itself but its `Iterator`.

Your for loop can thus be formulated that way:

```
for (Iterator<Foo> i = fooService.getFooList(); i.hasNext();) {
    Foo foo= i.next();
}
```

See the [language specifications about the `for` loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) for more information